# Dell E6500 sound missing - why?

Tags: audio, sound-card, dell-latitude

I have Dell E6500 (figured out on Stackoverlow to be quite popular notebook). I have manually installed Windows XP Professional, with all drivers from Dell CD. However, there are some problems with YouTube – as I enter YouTube, movies do not load, and Firefox takes 90% of CPU. There is also problem with sound sometimes go missing… Missing sound usually occurs after I run VmWare Workstation. Of course everything is ok after reboot.
I suspect some connection between Sound Card and some strange tool named “SRS Premium Sound”. Do you have any experience with missing sound on this computers?

Installed drivers:
A07_R212481.exe
APP_WIN_R205002.EXE
Dell_System-Software_A03_R214472.exe
DRVR_WIN_R213367.EXE
R182522.exe
R211478.exe
RICOH_MULTI-DEVICE_A00_R215879.exe
SRS_Premium-Sound_A00_R213368.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble with my sound settings on the e6500, but I'm running Windows 7
All you could do probably is uninstall the drivers (through the hardware manager) and try reinstalling them.

Installing the Dell drivers gave me an IDT sound manager, so perhaps download the newest drivers using your service tag.

Edit: looked for a link where you had to fill in your service tag, but mine auto-directs me to the Dutch website.

Comment: Yes, there was (is?) and issue with langugage. As I was checking for Polish version of Windows, the correct drivers were those, that appeared when searching English drivers (do sound drivers really have language versions?).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Flash installed?  YouTube won't operate correctly without it.

What drivers did you install for your sound card?

Comment: Yes, Flash is installed. Youtube works after reboot. List of drivers in question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I had a similar problem with my webcam after using a webcam extension for oovoo. What may have happened is after you ran VmWare Workstation, it could have changed what your default speakers were. If that is the case, you'll have to go to playback mixers via the volume option in the bottom right of the start bar and manually change the speakers until you find the ones that work.

Answer (score 1):

Disabled and then re-enabled IDT High Definition Audio CODEC in the device manager.  Audio came back and I got to avoid rebooting to fix the audio.

Not really a fix, but a work around for when it does go out.

Answer (score 0):

Some clues: when checking for drivers in Dell website do not care about Windows language, always search English. This is how I have found some driver update – it seems to be working, despite potential language conflict.